# Why is axios response empty with this code?

Tags: vue.js, axios, stripe-payments, checkout

I am receiving the console message:

"IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId."

I believe that sessionId is empty because response.data is "empty string" from console.log(response.data).

This code comes from the github of a tutorial. It should be very close to correct, but I believe there is a slight inaccuracy.

```
stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
    cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: results
}, function(err, session) {
    response.send(session)
});
```

---

```
axios.get('https://us-central1-webstore-vuejs.cloudfunctions.net/CheckoutSession', {
    params: {
        products: data
    }
}).then(response => {
    this.sessionId = response.data  

    console.log(response.data)
          
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({                 
        sessionId: this.sessionId.id
    }).then(function(result) {              
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
}, function(err, session) {
    response.send(session)
});
```

I suspect that you've got an error happening here; I'd log it and see what it might be.

Ideally you should always at least throw (or ideally handle!) errors so that you know when something goes wrong.